# when an item in an out of the 2 spinner view is selected, other should be auto filled. All this using just a local json file in assets folder

Tags: java, android, json

I am new to android. I have 2 spinner view and want to make an activity where if any one of the spinner view item is selected the other spinner item gets selected automatically depending on the one selected in one of the 2 spinner view. and all the data for the spinner view is in a local json file in asset folder

my java file is,

```
package com.example.vibhanshutyagi.spinnerexample2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String json = null;
    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {

        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("CustomerList.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            try {

                Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner_01);
                List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

                Spinner spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner_02);
                List<String> item = new ArrayList<>();

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
                JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("Sheet1");

                JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
                JSONArray array1 = obj1.getJSONArray("Sheet2");
            /*this.setTitle(root.getString("title"));*/

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    items.add(object.getString("FIELD1"));
                //    item.add(object.getString("FIELD2"));
                //    items.add(object.getString("FIELD3"));
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                //    items.add(object.getString("FIELD1"));
                    item.add(object.getString("FIELD2"));
                }

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
                spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}`
```

my json file is,

```
    {    "Sheet1": [   {
    "FIELD1": "BEDROOM 1",
    "FIELD2": "1"


  },   {
    "FIELD1": "BEDROOM 2",
    "FIELD2": "2"

  },   {
    "FIELD1": "BEDROOM 3",
    "FIELD2": "3"

  },   {
    "FIELD1": "LIVING ROOM",
    "FIELD2": "4"

  },   {
    "FIELD1": "DINING ROOM",
    "FIELD2": "5"

  },   {
    "FIELD1": "KITCHEN",
    "FIELD2": "6"

  },   {
    "FIELD1": "TOILET 1",
    "FIELD2": "7"

  } ],   "Sheet2": [
    {
      "FIELD1": "BEDROOM 1",
      "FIELD2": "1"


    },
    {
      "FIELD1": "BEDROOM 2",
      "FIELD2": "2"

    },
    {
      "FIELD1": "BEDROOM 3",
      "FIELD2": "3"

    },
    {
      "FIELD1": "LIVING ROOM",
      "FIELD2": "4"

    },
    {
      "FIELD1": "DINING ROOM",
      "FIELD2": "5"

    },
    {
      "FIELD1": "KITCHEN",
      "FIELD2": "6"

    },
    {
      "FIELD1": "TOILET 1",
      "FIELD2": "7"
    }   ] }
```

my spinner_layout xml file is,

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

my main xml file is,

```
   <Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spinner_01"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   android:layout_marginRight="16dp">    </Spinner>    <Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spinner_02"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">    </Spinner>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: if you want to select the second spinner automatically, then you don't need to create the second spinner, because if you select Filed one then you know the value for Field one, so take `TextView` set text in it according to your choice.

Comment: I saw your code, Why are you taking two spinners, make Custome Bean and Custome Adapter and populate bean object .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanna do:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    String json = null;
    Spinner spinner;
    Spinner spinner1;

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {

        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("CustomerList.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {

            spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner_01);
            List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
            spinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner_02);
            List<String> item = new ArrayList<>();

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("Sheet1");

            JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray array1 = obj1.getJSONArray("Sheet2");
        /*this.setTitle(root.getString("title"));*/

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                items.add(object.getString("FIELD1"));
                //    item.add(object.getString("FIELD2"));
                //    items.add(object.getString("FIELD3"));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                //    items.add(object.getString("FIELD1"));
                item.add(object.getString("FIELD2"));
            }

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        spinner1.setSelection(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer is neither helpful nor does it solves my purpose,  but thanks for helping Saba

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by autofilling? What I understood from this sentence `if any one of the spinner view item is selected the other spinner item gets selected automatically` is you wanna select the otherone based on the position of the current one.

Comment: As we select an item in spinner 1 then in spinner 2 some item related to that item must be auto selected and vice versa, but the data related to that is stored in a local json file

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code in the end of your `onCreate` method

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                spinner1.setSelection(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                spinner.setSelection(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```

Here is snapshot of the output
[image: Output]

Comment: Is it not compiling or is it not according to your requirement?

Comment: the application on the AVD is not opening

Comment: Please share your logcat crash data